# Will try-with-resources always close the resources

Tags: java, try-with-resources

Will try-with-resources always close the resource irrespective of error condition? I mean consider below code:

```
try (BufferedReader br =
               new BufferedReader(new FileReader(path))) {
    return br.readLine();
}
```

Will `br` always be closed? I have read Oracle documentation which says:

> it will be closed regardless of whether the try statement completes normally or abruptly

So it will work whether program runs normally or throws exception. But what about conditions like `System.exit` or `JVM` crashes? I know these conditions won't work for `finally` block. So is there a condition at which try-with-resources fail?

This just I am asking for curiosity, can someone please shed light on this?

Comment: No, it also won't close the resources in case a nuclear blast vaporizes the computer. But luckily we don't need to worry about those cases.

Comment: Why sarcastic? Wrong to ask doubt?

Comment: The official docs don't outright say it ( https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html ) but it does seem to lean in the direction of closure. I assume "after the program is finished with it" is after the try (resource) ends.

Comment: Set a breakpoint in the readers `close` method call `System.exit` in the `try` block and see what happens.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

try-with-resource is just a syntactic sugar to save you the hassle of messing with a `finally` clause. Nothing "java-ish" that happens inside the `try` block would prevent the resource from closing - returning, throwing an exception, etc.

Anything that terminates the JVM abruptly (such as calling `System#exit`, killing the JVM's process, unplugging the computer, etc.) won't be handled, just as it's not handled by an old-fashioned `finally` clause.

Comment: Refer to [JLS Sec 14.20.3.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-14.html#jls-14.20.3.1) for the "desugared" form of a try-with-resources block.

Answer (score 2):

If the VM terminates in any way any memory and file channels will be freed anyway. If you have custom code in the respective close operation and the VM crashes I expect that this code will not be run but that almost never happens. Most errors are handled by the VM and in any of that cases the close method will be called.